Data table is getting blurred on Shiny dashboard
I have the shiny app with two data tables "DF1010" and its derivative "DF1010_2" reactive by SelectInput(). The code appears to have no bugs. But when I run it, I am encountering two problems:

Both data tables are getting blurred when the fourth thru sixth columns of "DF1010" are filled in.

The calculation in the following part of the code is not working:
observe({data$DF1010[[7]] <- data$DF1010[[4]] + (data$DF1010[[5]] - data$DF1010[[6]])}) 



The code itself is not giving any errors, though there must be something wrong with it as per the problems depicted above.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)

DF1010 = data.table(
            "Date" = as.character(c("01/01/2020")),
            "DocName" = as.character(0),
            "TransactionContent" = as.character(0),
        "InitialBalance" = as.numeric(0),
            "Debit" = as.numeric(0),
            "Credit" = as.numeric(0),
            "ClosingBalance" = as.numeric(0),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cc <- strsplit(DF1010$"Date","/",fixed=TRUE)
d <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(DF1010$"Date"))-2]
m <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(DF1010$"Date"))-1]
y <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(DF1010$"Date"))]
DF1010$"Date_2" <- paste0(y,"-",m,"-",d)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "IFRS"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
        menuItem("ACCOUNTING", tabName = "Accounting", 
          menuItem("Short-term assets", tabName = "CurrentAssets", 
            menuItem("1000.Cash", tabName = "cash1000",
              menuSubItem("1010.Cash in the cash register", tabName = "table1010")
      )
     )
        )
      )
    ),

 dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "home",
            h2("Welcome to the Home Page")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "table1010",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 8,
            "Journal of accounting entries",
            rHandsontableOutput("table1010_Item1")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Selection by Date and/or DocName",
            selectInput("choices", label=NULL,
                        choices = c("Selection by Date", "Selection by DocName", "Selection by Date and DocName")),   #"choice 3" is added
            uiOutput("nested_ui")
          ),
          column(
            width = 12,
            label=NULL,
            rHandsontableOutput("table1010_Item2")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    data$DF1010 <- as.data.frame(DF1010)
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table1010_Item1))
      data$DF1010<- hot_to_r(input$table1010_Item1)
  }) 

 observe({
    data$DF1010[[7]] <- data$DF1010[[4]] + (data$DF1010[[5]] - data$DF1010[[6]])
 })

  output$table1010_Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$DF1010[,c(1:7)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d/%m/%Y", type = "date")
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1010_Item1)) {
      DFA1010 <- hot_to_r(input$table1010_Item1)

      cc <- strsplit(DFA1010$"Date","/",fixed=TRUE)
      d <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(DFA1010$"Date"))-2]
      m <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(DFA1010$"Date"))-1]
      y <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(DFA1010$"Date"))]
      DFA1010$"Date_2" <- paste0(y,"-",m,"-",d)
  
      data$DF1010 <- DFA1010
  
      if (!any(is.na(input$dates))) {
        DF1010_1 <- data$DF1010
        selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                              as.Date(input$dates[2]), by = "day")
        data$DF1010_2 <- DF1010_1[as.Date(DF1010_1$"Date_2") %in% selected_dates, ]
      } else {
        selected_dates2 <- unique(DFA1010$"Date")
        data$DF1010_2 <- DFA1010[DFA1010$"Date" %in% selected_dates2, ]
      } 
    }
  })

  observe ({ 
    if (!is.null(input$text) && input$text != "") {
      updateTextInput(session, "text", value = input$text)
      data$DF1010_2 <- data$DF1010[data$DF1010$"DocName" == input$text, ]
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (!any(is.na(input$dates)) && input$choices == "Selection by Date and DocName") {
      DF1010_1 <- data$DF1010
      selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                            as.Date(input$dates[2]), by = "day")
      data$DF1010_2 <- DF1010_1[as.Date(DF1010_1$"Date_2") %in% selected_dates & DF1010_1$"DocName" == input$text, ]
    } else if (!is.null(input$dates) && !any(is.na(input$dates))) {
      DF1010_1 <- data$DF1010
      selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                            as.Date(input$dates[2]), by = "day")
      data$DF1010_2 <- DF1010_1[as.Date(DF1010_1$"Date_2") %in% selected_dates, ]
    } else if (!is.null(input$text) && input$text != "") {
      data$DF1010_2 <- data$DF1010[data$DF1010$"DocName" == input$text, ]
    } else {
      data$DF1010_2 <- data$DF1010
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1010_Item2)) {
      data$DF1010_2 <- hot_to_r(input$table1010_Item2)
    }
  })


  output$nested_ui <- renderUI({
    if (input$choices == "Selection by Date") {
      dateRangeInput("dates", "Choose a period:", format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                     start = "2020-01-01", end = Sys.Date())
    } else if (input$choices == "Selection by DocName") {
      textInput("text", "Type a DocName:")
    } else if (input$choices == "Selection by Date and DocName") {
      fluidRow(
        dateRangeInput("dates", "Choose a period:", format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                       start = "2000-01-01", end = Sys.Date()),
        textInput("text", "Type a DocName:")
      )
    }
  })

  output$table1010_Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$DF1010_2[,c(1:7)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d/%m/%Y", type = "date")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)


The observe({...}) described in your question is running into an infinite loop if you alter the data. Is it working if you replace it with observeEvent(input$table1010_Item1, {...})? This listens to changes of the rhandsontable object. Also please consider giving minimal examples, your code is full of unnecessary details which are not needed in order to reproduce the problem (e.g. several menuItem).

Hi Jan. The reason why I do not use observeEvent() is that, as you know, this function requires actionButton() as a trigger. But I want the table to do calculation automatically as I enter data. Hence, observe() seems to be a proper function. However, you are right that it is running into an infinite loop. Do you have any other ideas how to tackle it?

Why should observeEvent() requireactionButton()? I tested it yesterday using observeEvent(input$table1010_Item1, {...}) and the calculation was done when I entered the data.

Jan, as per your suggestion I have amended the relevant part of the code as observeEvent(input$table1010_Item1, { data$DF1010[,7] <- data$DF1010[,4] + (data$DF1010[,5] - data$DF1010[,6])}). Still unsuccessful, however.

Yet, the calculation is working for both observe() and observeEvent() only when selectInput() and relevant parts are excluded from the code. When selectInput() comes to interplay, calculation is NOT done any more.
